# What does # means in SVG's format in CSS' @font-face rule

Tags: html, css, svg

Question 1: What does the `#` means in a font-face rule when using SVG format? 
Almost everyone uses this, but I can't understand what's the point. The

Question 2: Is it still needed to to the #iefix since Internet Explorer 6 was dropped?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Font';
    src: url('css/fonts/Font.eot');
    src: url('css/fonts/Font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('css/fonts/Font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('css/fonts/Font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('css/fonts/Font.svg#SOME_RANDOM_STUFF_HERE') format('svg');
         font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: Your question appears to have a hanging "The".

Comment: Thanks @NicoO I made a search but I didn't find that answer. Now I understand that I can create a single SVG file for all my fonts. Reducing my overall HTTP GETs.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way older IE interpret font declarations. If you don't add the `#iefix` you will have issues with IE8 and before.

Comment: But for IE9++, is this needed? I only support IE9/10/11